# Communicating with Java from PHP

Tags: java, php

I have a website that is a companion app for a java application. Namely, the web app fetches information from the java app and inputs it into my database and lets the user access this information. Right now I have the system set up so the Java app posts to the website's php files when I tell the Java app to.

However, I am wanting to set the system up so that the java app posts to the website when a command is issued from the website, such as a refresh command. Is this possible?

Comment: can you replace every use of **it** with either 'java app' or 'php app'

Comment: yeah, I've edited it. sorry for the unclarity @Dagon

Comment: Does your java app run continuously, like a daemon? Or do you start it on demand, let it service the command, and then shut down?

Comment: @chris The java app performs tasks for an indefinite amount of time, until it fails or the user stops it.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely vague. You should not think of the problem in terms of "posting from PHP to Java", in fact every HTTP request is simply that - an HTTP request. PHP and Java both offer several ways to respond to HTTP requests. It's up to you to compose the scripts that will respond to each request. Think of this in terms of the requests you need to make and the responses they should receive, then focus on writing a script for each of those interactions.

Comment: @DanielvanderMerwe Use servlets

Answer (score 0):

You can call Java directly from PHP. Zend Server and PHP/Java bridge both enable this. Depending on your requirements one of those may be appropriate.

Alternatively you can make use of message oriented middleware. This requires you to install and run a message broker such as RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ. However client libraries are available for much more than just PHP and Java.

Both of these would be better alternatives than relying on HTTP requests.

Comment: I agree, if this is all on the same server it would be much more appropriate to handle this all server-side without mucking about with HTTP.

Comment: It's a java app, not a java applet, so it's running per instance base on people's computers.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question. It was never mentioned that it is some client side application.